# Process TEXT BLOBs fields in MySQL line by line

Tags: mysql

I have a MEDIUMTEXT blob in a table, which contains paths, separated by new line characters. I'd like to add a "/" to the begging of each line if it is not already there. Is there a way to write a query to do this with built-in procedures?

I suppose an alternative would be to write a Python script to get the field, convert to a List, process each line and update the record. There aren't that many records in the DB, so I can take the processing delay (if it doesn't lock the entire DB or table). About 8K+ rows.

Either way would be fine. If second option is recommended, do I need to know of specific locking schematics before getting into this -- as this would be run on a live prod DB (of course, I'd take a DB snapshot). But in place updates would be best to not have downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key, t text );

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 'path1\npath2\npath3');

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+-------------------+
| id | t                 |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | path1
path2
path3 |
+----+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update mytable set t = concat('/', replace(t, '\n', '\n/'));

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+----------------------+
| id | t                    |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | /path1
/path2
/path3 |
+----+----------------------+
```

However, I would strongly recommend to store each path on its own row, so you don't have to think about this. In SQL, each column should store one value per row, not a set of values.

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution! We store each path as a single object, and they bundled together for simple file copying. I tried to normalize everything I could not not a DB expert at all.